# Best practices for identifiers/classes names in browser extensions

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

In extensions (I'm praticularly focused on Chrome's extensions), css identifiers and classes injected in a page may enter in conflict with other elements on the page.

I'm trying to define their name with an extension prefix, but it's not perfectly sure. So, is there a way to define scurely names of css ids/classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible if "perfectly sure" is your requirement. Someone could always download your extension, look at the classnames you're using, then change their website's CSS to conflict with (or more likely attempt to override) your classnames. This is a feature, not a bug; extensions extend web pages, so they're supposed to be able to commingle with and alter their DOMs.

If you wanted to invent a system where others would not intentionally conflict with yours, why not use the Java namespace scheme: take a domain you own, and use it as a prefix, like com-example-myclassname? Slightly less readable and no more secure would be either the ID of your extension or a randomly generated SHA-1 hexcoded hash:

- abcdefghijklmnop-myclassname
- da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709-myclassname

I'm intentionally not including dynamic solutions here because CSS typically isn't dynamic in a Chrome extension or app. Moreover, CSP would probably make this approach anything but straightforward (which is a good thing).